# Oracle query to count no of days

Tags: oracle

I have STATUS column.  Values are APPROVED,PENDING,REJECTED. I have to count how many days the ticket is in PENDING.

```
ID      Status       Date
BNM       Pend        11/nov/16
BNM       Pend        12/nov/16
ABC       Pend        11/nov/16
BNM       Pend        12/nov/16
ABC       Pend        11/nov/16
ABC       Pend       12/nov/16
CVD       pend        11/nov/16
CVD       pend        12/nov/16
BNM       Pend        10/NOV/16
ABC       Pend         10/NOV/16
CVD       Pend         10/NOV/16
CVD       Approv        09/NOV/16
CVD       PEND           08/NOV/16
```

When i run the query on 13/nov/16.

```
BNM-3 days
ABC-3 days
"CVD-5days" (counted as 5 days but it should count as 3 days).
```

Counting from 08 nov  but it should count from 10 nov 16. there was an update on status on 09 nov 16.

```
Select t.ID,(t.date),t2.nofdays,t1.status
     from table1 t
     inner join 
         (  select tt.id,max(tt.days) 
                  from table1 tt
               group by ...)t2
                  on t.id=t2.id
 inner join 
        (  (  select ttt.id,max(ttt.days), count(ttt.days) as noofdays

                  from table1 ttt 
                where status like 'PEND%'
               group by ...)t2

            on t1.id=t2.id and t1.date=t2.date

where trunc(t.date)=trunc(sysdate-1)
group by .....)
```

Comment: please define "how many days the ticket is pending". Assuming "ticket" means "ID" (in this case it is easy to guess, but in general please don't make us guess, tell us what "ticket" means in your data). Then - "pending" meaning what, from the oldest day with status "pending", so that there was no other status since that date? Or what else? How do you measure "how many days" based ONLY ON THE DATA and nothing else? (Showing your query is important, but it can't substitute for explaining the logic in complete details in plain language.)

Comment: Also - what's the point of duplicate rows in the table? What's the meaning of, for example, having two rows for BNM, both with Pend status and same date (12/nov/16)? Could it also happen that you have two rows for an ID, both with the same date but DIFFERENT status? And if so, which takes precedence (which comes "before" the other)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to find count of actual days in pending. You can do this by running this select:

```
SELECT (MAX(t.status_date) - MIN(t.status_date) + 1) nodays, -- +1 is for adding a current day of pending
       t.id
  FROM table1 t
  JOIN (
        -- For every ID, find max date of not pending status or return "01/01/1900"
        SELECT t.id,
                NVL(MAX(CASE
                           WHEN t.status <> 'Pend' THEN
                            status_date
                         END),
                     to_date('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) max_date
          FROM table1 t
         GROUP BY t.id
        --
        ) m
-- keep only rows that are newer than max_date
    ON t.id = m.id
   AND t.status_date > m.max_date
--
 GROUP BY t.id;
```

This select will return a number of days from first pending status to last pending status.